# How to calculate the characteristic function of $\log S_1$ and $\log X_n$?

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions, central-limit-theorem

> At a time $0$ a share has a value of $x$ and at a time ${kt \over n}$ $(t >0, k,n \in \mathbb N, k \leq n)$  it has a value of $$X_k :=p^{{tk \over n}} S_1\cdots S_kx,$$
>   where $p>0$ and the $S_i$ are i.i.d. random variables where 
>   $$
> P[S_i=1+{\sigma \over \sqrt{n}}]=P[S_i=(1+{\sigma \over \sqrt{n}})^{-1}]={1 \over 2},\, \sigma>0.
> $$
>
> How can I calculate the characteristic function of $\log S_1$ and $\log X_n$?

Some help here would be much appreciated. Also, how does one show that $\log X_n$ in distribution converges to a normally distributed random variable $Y$ and what is the parameter? 
Some approaches would be nice.

Comment: You are given the distribution of $S_n$ (basically, a kind of Bernoulli) and you cannot find the characteristic function of $\log S_n$? This makes it hard to imagine any answer to the other parts of your question which could prove useful to you...

Comment: And now a bounty is proposed to cancel the defects of the question, which it does not, obviously. Is it so difficult to add any kind of context to this?

Comment: Now I did. Stil dont know how to show that it converges to a normally distributed random variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I calculated

$$\phi_{\log S_1}(z)={1 \over 2} ((1+{\sigma\over \sqrt{n}})^{iz}+(1+{\sigma\over \sqrt{n}})^{-iz})$$ and $$\phi_{\log X_n}(z)= p^{izt}x^{iz}{1 \over 2^n} ((1+{\sigma\over \sqrt{n}})^{iz}+(1+{\sigma\over \sqrt{n}})^{-iz})^n$$

Comment: But I thought 
$e^{ita}=e^{it \log (1 + { \sigma \over \sqrt{n}})}= (1 + { \sigma \over \sqrt{n}})^{it}?$

Comment: If so, we got the same characteristic functions, if not, then  I am wrong.

Comment: I dont fully understand. So my equation in the former comment is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Your solution still helped! Will simplify terms by defining them by a variable as you did in future ($a = \log (...)$) to make it more comfortable to read.